# Android studio emulator wrong ownership on runtime directory

Tags: android, ubuntu, flutter, android-emulator

When I start the emulator in Android Studio :
(Used Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS)

> Emulator: Warning: QStandardPaths: wrong ownership on runtime
>   directory /run/user/1000/snap.android-studio, 0 instead of 1000
>   ((null):0, (null))
>
> Emulator: Warning: QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL
>   context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled ((null):0, (null))

Comment: Did you get this working !!? I'm getting same error.

Comment: I just started testing with a real device)

Comment: Sounds like good workaround. Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

a) likely that snap install is crap, better install the standalone version of [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio)

or run `sudo chown -R 1000:1000 /run/user/1000/snap.android-studio` to fix the permissions.

b) you need to install GL drivers, assuming you have a suitable graphics card available.

One can check these GL drivers with `glxinfo -B`.

Comment: Thanks i will try

Comment: @AndriyTsvok Did it fix the problem?